# Why is pd.series(cell_list) deleting the last elements of my cell_list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My existing data frame 'error' is like this,

| Bal1 | Bal2 | Bal3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 | 1 |
| 3 | NaN | 3 |

```
I want to add a fourth column Bal4= [1,2,3,4,5]
```

so, i do
import pandas as pd

error['Bal4']= pd.Series(Bal4)

But then I get 'error' as

| Bal1 | Bal2 | Bal3 | Bal4 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 3 | NaN | 3 | 2 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

the rest 3,4,5 of Bal4 is getting deleted, why?

Comment: Please use backticks to format your table properly. It's quite hard to understand currently.

Comment: @AJH, thanks for notifying I have formatted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
error = pd.concat([error, pd.DataFrame({'Bal4': Bal4})], axis=1)
```

```
print(error)

   Bal2  Bal3  Bal4
0   2.0   1.0     1
1   NaN   3.0     2
2   NaN   NaN     3
3   NaN   NaN     4
4   NaN   NaN     5
```